# Including one html file inside another

Tags: html, include

My web page is split into several pieces(html files). I am trying to include everything in on

```
<!--#include file="../handlers/test_header.html" -->
<!--#include file="../handlers/test_body.html" -->
<!--#include file="../handlers/test_footer.html" -->
```

This doesn't work out. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: why is this "*not working out*"? Have you enabled *SSI* on your web-server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SSI try this code, if not you must enable SSI on your server

```
<!--#include virtual="../handlers/test_header.html" -->
```